# How to get the href of an a tag that is inside a ul tag that repeats multiple times?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

What I want to do is get the href of the a tag inside a ul that repeats multiple times: For example:

```
<div class="contain">
    <div id="0">
        <ul class="drop">
            <li><a href="some_link"></a></li>
            <li><a href="some_link_1"></a></li>
            <li><a href="some_link_2"></a></li>
            <li><a href="some_link_3"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="contain">
        <div id="1">
            <ul class="drop">
                <li><a href="some_link_4"></a></li>
                <li><a href="some_link_5"></a></li>
                <li><a href="some_link_6"></a></li>
                <li><a href="some_link_7"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contain">
            <div id="a">
                <ul class="drop">
                    <li><a href="some_link_7"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="some_link_8"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="some_link_9"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="some_link"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

What I want is to get all the href inside this piece of code. How would I do?

Comment: All the href inside the ul elements (as stated) or all href in document? The current accepted answer does something closer to the latter in getting all a tag hrefs wherever they are.

Comment: All the href inside the ul element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be more accurate, based on what you have said about all `href` within `ul` elements to use:

```
links = [i['href'] for i in soup.select('.drop [href]')]
```

This uses the class name of the parent `ul` (the second fastest selector method) combined with child `[href]` which will pick up all href attributes within (not only from `a` tags but anything within the parent `ul`).

With the other answer you will get all `href`associated with `a` tags in a document irrespective of whether there is a parent `ul`.

Answer (score 1):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<div class="contain">
    <div id="0">
        <ul class="drop">
            <li><a href="some_link"></a></li>
            <li><a href="some_link_1"></a></li>
            <li><a href="some_link_2"></a></li>
            <li><a href="some_link_3"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="contain">
        <div id="1">
            <ul class="drop">
                <li><a href="some_link_4"></a></li>
                <li><a href="some_link_5"></a></li>
                <li><a href="some_link_6"></a></li>
                <li><a href="some_link_7"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contain">
            <div id="a">
                <ul class="drop">
                    <li><a href="some_link_7"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="some_link_8"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="some_link_9"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="some_link"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print "The URL:", a['href']
```

This would print all the `href`

```
The URL: some_link
The URL: some_link_1
The URL: some_link_2
The URL: some_link_3
The URL: some_link_4
The URL: some_link_5
The URL: some_link_6
The URL: some_link_7
The URL: some_link_7
The URL: some_link_8
The URL: some_link_9
The URL: some_link
```

To get the list of all the links you can simply use:

```
hrefLinks = [EachLink['href'] for EachLink in  soup.find_all('a', href=True)]
```

Comment: Is their a way to store this in a list or something? Also thanks for the answer